# Prolog how to find sum of elements matrix

Tags: matrix, prolog, sum, find

I have matrix size `[n,n]`.

I need to find sum 
For example

```
1  2  3  4 
5  6  7  8 
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16

sum = 3+4+7+8
```

I need to find sum of elements of first quadrant matrix

Comment: I indented your code - waiting approval. Without it it's very hard to know what you want---

Comment: ty for this
can you help me?

Comment: I'm beginner in Prolog swi , i can do it in JS or C#
maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Using `library(clpfd)`, which provides the useful `sum/3` and `transpose/2`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sum_first_quadrant(M, S) :-
    first_quadrant(M, Q),
    maplist(sum_, Q, Ss),
    sum_(Ss, S).

sum_(L, S) :-
    sum(L, #=, S).

first_quadrant(M, Q) :-
    transpose(M, T),
    reverse(T, RT),
    dichotomize(RT, RD),
    reverse(RD, D),
    transpose(D, TD),
    dichotomize(TD, Q).

dichotomize(M, D) :-
    length(M, L),
    X #= L//2,
    dichotomize_(M, X, D).

dichotomize_(_, 0, []).
dichotomize_([H|T], X, [H|T2]) :-
    X #> 0,
    Y #= X - 1,
    dichotomize_(T, Y, T2).
```

Example:

```
?- sum_first_quadrant([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]], Z).
Z = 22 ;
false.
```

#### Note

You can get rid of the extraneous choice point in `dichotomize_` using `if_/3` and `(=)/3` from [library `reif`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl):

```
dichotomize_(L, X, D) :-
    X #>= 0,
    if_(X = 0,
        D = [],
        (   Y #= X - 1,
            L = [H|T],
            D = [H|T2],
            dichotomize_(T, Y, T2)
        )
    ).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    %-matrix
data([[1,2,18,23],
      [5,6,10,10],
      [9,10,11,12],
      [13,14,15,16]]).
%-Sum
main(S):-
    data(Ms),
    length(Ms,N),
    Mdl is N//2,
    sum_matr(Ms,1,N,Mdl,0,S).

%+Matrix,+RowCounter,+Length,+Midle,+Acc,-S
sum_matr([R|Rs],I,K,Mdl,Acc,S):-
    I=<Mdl, I1 is I+1,
    findEnd(R,Mdl,ResList),
    sum_row(ResList,Mdl,I,K,0,Srow),
    Acc1 is Acc + Srow,
    sum_matr(Rs,I1,K,Mdl,Acc1,S).

sum_matr(_,I,_,Mdl,S,S):-
    I>Mdl.

%+Row,+Counter,+I,+K,+Acc,-Sum
sum_row([X|Xs],C,I,K,Acc,S):-
    C<K,
    Acc1 is Acc+X,
    C1 is C+1,
    sum_row(Xs,C1,I,K,Acc1,S).
sum_row(_,C,_,K,S,S):-
    C>=K.
%+List, +Position, -End
findEnd(E, 0, E).
findEnd([_|T], N, E):-
    N>0,
    N1 is N-1,
    findEnd(T, N1, E).
```